# Using cloud function parameterized configuration with Typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to follow [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#params) to use parameterized configuration in my Firebase cloud functions.

The example they give is in Javascript, in particular in how they import `defineInt` and `defineString` from `firebase-functions/params`.

```
const { defineInt, defineString } = require('firebase-functions/params');
```

But all my functions code is in Typescript so I tried to translate that into:

```
import {defineInt} from "firebase-functions/lib/params";
```

Since apparently `firebase-functions/params` cannot be resolved.

But then when I try to deploy my functions, I get the following error message:

> Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to
> generate manifest from function source: Error
> [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/params' is not
> defined by "exports" in
> /Users/sarbogast/dev/blindly/blindly/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/package.json

Any idea what's the proper way to import those functions in Typescript?

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. You're importing correctly from a syntax point of view, but it seems that there is no such module. `Package subpath './params' is not defined by "exports" in /Users/.../functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/package.json`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following import should resolve the issue:

```
import { https } from "firebase-functions/v1";
import { defineString } from "firebase-functions/params"; // no /lib

const welcomeMessage = defineString("WELCOME_MESSAGE");

export const hello = https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.send("Message: " + welcomeMessage);
});
```

Dependencies:

```
"firebase-admin": "^11.2.0",
"firebase-functions": "^4.0.1"
```

And given that the error is an `eslint` one and it doesn't make sense in that context, adding the following to `.eslintrc.js` turns the blocking error into a more persmissive warning:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    rules: {
        ...
        "import/no-unresolved": "warn",
    },
};
```

Comment: You should have `welcomeMessage.value()`, when inside the `.onRequest`, right?

Comment: I had the same issue when targeting the "latest" version. Rolled back to this version fixed the import issue.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue with the following firebase functions SDK (node: 16.x.x)

```
"firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
"firebase-functions": "^3.18.0"
```

I changed how I imported the `defineSecret` and it's now working. I didn't have to change the `.eslintrc` either

```js
import { defineSecret } from "firebase-functions/v2/params"
```